# Define 2D polygon area and check if point is inside at runtime

Tags: gdscript, godot-4

I'm trying to write a GDScript (using Godot *4*) function that creates a new component at a specific `Vector2` position. This works quite well with the following code:

```
func _create_thing(at_position):
    var component = load("res://thing.tscn").instantiate() as Node2D
    component.position = at_position
    %PlayfieldNode2D.add_child(component)
```

Now I'm trying to restrict where players can create something. I want to define a polygon shape in the editor to determine the area where this is allowed. My thought was to create an `Area2D` node with a `CollisionPolygon2D` shape and then do something like this:

```
    if %AllowedArea2D.contains_point(at_position):
         # creation logic here
```

This is pseudo-code, because I found no `contains_point(...)` or similar method in [the Area2D docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_area2d.html). I looked through the docs of other related Node types such as the [`CollisionPolygon2D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_collisionpolygon2d.html), [`Polygon2D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_polygon2d.html) and several others, but found no solution yet.

Bottom line: how can I define a polygon shape in Godot 4 and later check if a specific `Vector2` is inside that polygon?

Answer (score 3):

Minutes after posting I find the answer myself, was tempted to delete my question because it was so simple, but it might help someone else too...

Although I found no method on one of the object's classes themselves, it *is* on a `Geometry2D` helper class, specifically [the `is_point_in_polygon(point, polygon)` method](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_geometry2d.html#class-geometry2d-method-is-point-in-polygon) does what you need here. For example:

```
    if Geometry2D.is_point_in_polygon(at_position, %CollisionPolygon2D.polygon):
         # creation logic here
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought I was gonna have to go instantiate a whole Geometry2D, not realizing this was a static method.

Answer (score 2):

I know you found an alternative approach. However, originally you wanted something that worked with `Area2D`. Well, here is that:

```
var query := PhysicsPointQueryParameters2D.new()
query.collide_with_areas = true
query.collide_with_bodies = false
query.position = at_position
var result := get_world_2d().direct_space_state.intersect_point(query)
var in_the_area := false
for entry in result:
    if entry.collider == area_2d:
        in_the_area = true
        break

prints(in_the_area)
```

Comment: Best example about using `PhysicsPointQueryParameters2D` I've found so far